# Concatenation string with variable in emblem.js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, emblem.js

I need in Emblem.js to transmit to i18n helper concatenated string constant with variable value, How can i do it?

```
each item in model.items
    div
        t "dict.{{item}}"
```

returns error

```
Missing translation for key "dict.{{item}}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Handlebars 1.3+, you can use a [subexpression](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#subexpressions). First, write a string concatenation helper:

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('concat', function (a, b) {
    return a + b;
});
```

Then use it like this (sorry, I don't know Emblem so I'm going to use the normal stache syntax):

```
{{t (concat 'dict.' item)}}
```

Comment: thanks
just `t (concat-text "dict." item)` in emblem.js